# Searching with empty value returning empty array instead of entire data in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am creating a crud web app where I have rendered all the users into the table coming from third party API. Now, I am implementing a simple search box to filter table data according to **First Name**. But when I start typing and write first letter, It filters out the result but when I press backspace means empty the search box, It's returning me an empty array instead of providing me the entire data.

Below is my react redux code for the same:

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchAllUsersAction,searchByUserName} from '../../redux/actions/user';

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        users: state.usersData.users
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch,props) =>{
    return{
        fetchUsersAction: (pageNumber) => {dispatch(fetchAllUsersAction(pageNumber))},
        searchAction: (value)=>{dispatch(searchByUserName(value))}
    }
}

class Users extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let {users} = this.props;
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row mt-5">
                        <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={()=>this.props.fetchUsersAction(1)}>Fetch Users Data</button>

                        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search with user name..." onChange={(e) => this.props.searchAction(e.target.value)} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="row mt-5 table-responsive">
                        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                              <th scope="col">Email</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>

                          <tbody>
                                (users.length>0)?
                                    users.map((item,index)=>(
                                        <tr key={item.id}>           
                                             <td>{item.first_name}</td>           
                                             <td>{item.last_name}</td>           
                                             <td>{item.email}</td>           
                                        </tr>
                                    ))
                                :
                                <tr>
                                  <td colSpan="7">No users found!</td>   
                                </tr>
                            }
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>            
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

**Action**

```
import {
    FETCH_ALL_USERS_SUCCESS,
    SEARCH_BY_USER_NAME
} from './action-types';

function fetchAllUsersSuccess(usersData){
    return {
        type: FETCH_ALL_USERS_SUCCESS,
        users_data: usersData
    }
}

export function fetchAllUsersAction(pageNumber) {
    return function(dispatch){
        fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page='+pageNumber)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(json=>{
                dispatch(fetchAllUsersSuccess(json));
            })
    }
}

export function searchByUserName(value){
    return {type: SEARCH_BY_USER_NAME, value};
}
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
    FETCH_ALL_USERS_SUCCESS, 
    SEARCH_BY_USER_NAME
} from '../actions/action-types';


const initialState = {
    users: [] 
}

const userReducer = function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_ALL_USERS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                users: action.users_data.data
            }
        case SEARCH_BY_USER_NAME: {
              const {value} = action;
              const filtered_users = state.users.filter((val) => val.first_name.includes(value));
              return {...state, users:filtered_users};
            }                        
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

I have removed extra code & made it extremely easy to understand. Please help me guys to know where I am stucked.

Comment: `state.users.filter((val) => val.first_name.includes(value))` - is `value` really an empty string here?

Comment: Tested in console: `"test".includes("") //true`

Comment: You also save your filtered user array result back on top of the user array, so each change is filtering the previously filtered array.

Comment: Can you give an answer for the same please?

Comment: @messerbill, Yes It can contain empty string. Think of a search box, What happens when a user press backspace? Table will show the entire data and if any value is present in the search box then we will get the filtered result.

Comment: no my question was if `value` is really an empty string, rather than `null` or `undefined`

Comment: take note of what @yash has answered below. This is not really an answer to your question but he is also right.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are updating users array with empty array when some results to empty array.

1.Store api response in users array. also in filtered array
2.on search keep updating filtered array but filter on users array
3. Render filtered array and not users array

Comment: good point, this is really a bug. But should the list not be filled with stuff since he got some results by searching "Harry" for example and afterwards when deleting characters "Harr" should still be found in the remaining array? But yes, your point is correct

Comment: This is almost the correct answer. However, instead of storing the users in a full array and filtered array, store the users & the search term in Redux and filter from users in mapStateToProps. This will keep your data in Redux normalized and save you from doing unnecessary filters if the view doesn't need it.

Answer (score -1):

`onChange={(e) => this.props.searchAction(e.target.value)}`

THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM

First, you need to handle the change (change the state), then you need to do the action based on that state. When you call the action immediately, then you get the empty string ' '.

Here is an implementation I did using Hooks:

```
let { handleSearch } = props;
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
const handleChange = e => {
setQuery(e.target.value);
};
useEffect(() => {
handleSearch(query);
}, [query]);
return (
<>
<div className="TableHeader-search">
<InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
<InputGroupText className="TableHeader-search__icon">
<img src={mGlass} alt="search" />
</InputGroupText>
</InputGroupAddon>
<input
className="TableHeader-search__input"
type="text"
onChange={handleChange}
placeholder={"Search..."}
name="search"
value={query}
/>
</div>
</>
);
};
```

Notice the onChange action does the handleChange function first...
Good Luck.

Comment: this will make no difference at all. In the end `e.target.value` is passed to `props.searchAction`

Comment: Hmm, @messerbill is right. Please read carefully what I want and what I am getting.  BTW, Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not where the issue is at all. The correct answer was posted by Yash (you're filtering the users array so it's not there to filter on future typing).